# Highcharts in Asp.Nets

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Is it possible to integrate Pie Chart(Highcharts) with asp.net
I have tried with javascript in aspx page but it not working

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="js/data.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/exporting.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            var total = '<%=this.tot %>';
            var active = '<%=this.act %>';
            var inact = '<%=this.inact %>';


            var a = 124568;
            var t = 308257;
            var i = 140213;
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'pie',
                    options3d: {
                        enabled: true,
                        alpha: 45
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Total Subscriber Count in DSS'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Active and Inactive Count'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        innerSize: 100,
                        depth: 85
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Total Count',
                    data: [
                ['Total Customer Count', total],
                ['Active Customer Count', active],
                ['Inactive Customer Count', inact],
                    //                ['Oranges', 6],
                    //                ['Apples', 8],
                    //                ['Pears', 4],
                    //                ['Clementines', 4],
                    //                ['Reddish (bag)', 1],
                    //                ['Grapes (bunch)', 1]
            ]
                }]
            });
        });

        $(function () {

            $("input[id$='txtDate']").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
        });

</script>
```

the variable value is not get reflect in pie chart..at the same time pie chart is also not displaying

Answer (score 0):

Remove `,` after   `['Inactive Customer Count', inact],` at the end of this line.

Comment: What type of error your getting? Have you debug your code?